# Having trouble parsing SOAP webservice using the library ksoap2

Tags: web-services, soap, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

Here is the structure of my SOAP webservice which I need to get the **TxRefNum**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<tem:MakeCreditCardPayment>
<tem:objCreditCardBookingPaymentRow>
<tem:ProfessionalUserMappingStudioID>18</tem:ProfessionalUserMappingStudioID>
<tem:ConsumerUserMappingStudioID>5</tem:ConsumerUserMappingStudioID>
<tem:Cost>5</tem:Cost>
<tem:CardNumber>4111111111111111</tem:CardNumber>
<tem:CardHolderName>Shyam</tem:CardHolderName>
<tem:ExpirationDate>042020</tem:ExpirationDate>
<tem:CVV>123</tem:CVV>
<tem:ProfessionalSessionID>320</tem:ProfessionalSessionID>
<tem:TxRefNum></tem:TxRefNum>
</tem:objCreditCardBookingPaymentRow>
</tem:MakeCreditCardPayment>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using ksoap2 library to parse the following data, but am unable to find a proper solution to it. Here's what I am doing:

```
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            final String URL = NewURLs.BASE_URL + "api/PaymentService.asmx";
            final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/MakeCreditCardPayment";
            final String METHOD_NAME = "MakeCreditCardPayment";
            final String INNER_METHOD_NAME = "tem:objCreditCardBookingPaymentRow";
            // the above parameter can be taken from the users web service
            // (?WSDL)
            // url

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            SoapObject innerRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,INNER_METHOD_NAME);
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:ProfessionalUserMappingStudioID", bookingDetailsList.get(0).getUserMappingStudioID());
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:ConsumerUserMappingStudioID",loginCredentials.getUserMappingStudioId());
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:Cost",bookingDetailsList.get(0).getCost());
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:CardNumber", creditCardNo);
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:CardHolderName", creditCardHolder);
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:ExpirationDate", expirationDate);
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:CVV", cvv);
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:ProfessionalSessionID",bookingDetailsList.get(0).getProfessionalSessionID());
            innerRequest.addProperty("tem:TxRefNum", "");

            request.addProperty("tem:objCreditCardBookingPaymentRow",innerRequest);
            utils.sysOut("some text", "" + request);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            String str = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
            Log.v("TAG_SOAP_ACTION", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    SoapObject res=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
SoapObject t=(SoapObject)res.getProperty("MakeCreditCardPayment");

for(int i=0; i<t.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    SoapObject carditCard=(SoapObject)t.getProperty(i);
    String userID = carditCard.getProperty("ProfessionalUserMappingStudioID").toString();
}
```

Comment: what about the URL?

Comment: Which URL?? url is use to make request and get response.